# Force Tomcat6 to server all *.manifest files as text/cache-manifest?

Tags: cache, tomcat6, mime

How do I configure tomcat to server all `.manifest` files as `text/cache-manifest`? I'm trying to create an offline cache, and this is tripping me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to conf/web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```